# "How to use Facebook App Event In Flutter"

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, facebook-analytics

I would like to add the Facebook app-events to my Flutter project.
facebook_app_events: ^0.11.0,Android is working fine but IOS is not support my IOS platform :ios, '9.0' is using, so please suggest me.
getting error flutter ios Objective C:

```
  "method descriptor for Swift.ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral.init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral: A.ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType) -> A", referenced from:
      l_got.$ss43ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralP08extendeddeF0x0cdeF4TypeQz_tcfCTq in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(Permission.o)
  "_swift_getObjCClassFromMetadata", referenced from:
      @nonobjc __C.FlutterMethodChannel.__allocating_init(name: Swift.String, binaryMessenger: __C.FlutterBinaryMessenger) -> __C.FlutterMethodChannel in libfacebook_app_events.a(SwiftFacebookAppEventsPlugin.o)
  "(extension in Swift):Swift.Collection.map<A>((A.Element) throws -> A1) throws -> [A1]", referenced from:
      (extension in FBSDKCoreKit):__C.FBSDKAccessToken.permissions.getter : Swift.Set<FBSDKCoreKit.Permission> in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(AccessToken.o)
      (extension in FBSDKCoreKit):__C.FBSDKAccessToken.declinedPermissions.getter : Swift.Set<FBSDKCoreKit.Permission> in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(AccessToken.o)
      (extension in FBSDKCoreKit):__C.FBSDKAccessToken.expiredPermissions.getter : Swift.Set<FBSDKCoreKit.Permission> in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(AccessToken.o)
      static (extension in FBSDKCoreKit):__C.FBSDKSettings.loggingBehaviors.getter : Swift.Set<__C.FBSDKLoggingBehavior> in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(Settings.o)
      static (extension in FBSDKCoreKit):__C.FBSDKSettings.loggingBehaviors.setter : Swift.Set<__C.FBSDKLoggingBehavior> in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(Settings.o)
  "static (extension in Foundation):Swift.Set._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(__C.NSSet?) -> Swift.Set<A>", referenced from:
      (extension in FBSDKCoreKit):__C.FBSDKAccessToken.permissions.getter : Swift.Set<FBSDKCoreKit.Permission> in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(AccessToken.o)
      (extension in FBSDKCoreKit):__C.FBSDKAccessToken.declinedPermissions.getter : Swift.Set<FBSDKCoreKit.Permission> in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(AccessToken.o)
      (extension in FBSDKCoreKit):__C.FBSDKAccessToken.expiredPermissions.getter : Swift.Set<FBSDKCoreKit.Permission> in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(AccessToken.o)
      static (extension in FBSDKCoreKit):__C.FBSDKSettings.loggingBehaviors.getter : Swift.Set<__C.FBSDKLoggingBehavior> in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(Settings.o)
  "method descriptor for static Swift.Equatable.== infix(A, A) -> Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      l_got.$sSQ2eeoiySbx_xtFZTq in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(Permission.o)
      l_got.$sSQ2eeoiySbx_xtFZTq in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(Settings.o)
  "_swift_getTypeByMangledNameInContext", referenced from:
      ___swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledName in libFBSDKCoreKit.a(AccessToken.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on BSA’s iPhone.

Comment: Could you please provide full context of your code, environment and the output from `flutter doctor -v` command also.